# Prove that $ \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m^2 \pmod 7$ is $0, 1, 2$ or $4$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

**Problem : Prove that $ \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m^2 \pmod 7$ is $0, 1, 2$ or $4$.**

Hi all,

I've tried to do this in an odd-even method but it just doesn't seem to work out for me. The only one I can prove is for '$0$' - by taking $m = 0$ or multiples of $7$.

I tried proving by cases but I don't think that would be the ideal proof.

Can someone please help me with what I should do next?

Comment: $$\forall~m\in\Bbb Z~,~m\equiv_7\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3\}\implies m^2\equiv_7\{0,1,4,9\}\equiv_7\{0,1,4,2\}$$

Comment: I still cant figure out how to prove that if {0,±1,±2,±3} yields the required result, how would it suffice for all of m though?

Comment: @OP: You're working modulo $7$, i.e., in the group $\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z\simeq Z_7\simeq (\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3\},+_7)$ which has 7 elements ($+_7$ denotes addition modulo $7$), so checking for that set is sufficient. Basically, verifying the result for any one complete residue set modulo $7$ is sufficient to prove the result for all of $\Bbb Z$ under addition mod $7$.

Comment: Why do we ignore 4,5,6 in mod 7?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to emurate number of the form of $7k+r$ where $r \in \{ -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$.

That is is suffices to compute $r^2 \pmod{7}$ where $r \in \{ -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: So by using this set r, I understand I can get 1, 2 and 4 as well. So I should use some form of proof to show that this suffices ∀m∈Z ?

Comment: If it your first time working with this problem, you might want to work with $7k+r$ explicitly.

Comment: I still cant figure out how to prove that if {0,±1,±2,±3} yields the required result, how would it suffice for all of m though?

Comment: Each integer can be written as $7k+r$, and if we square them we get $(7k)^2+2(7kr)+r^2=7(k^2+2kr)+r^2$, hence the remainder only depends on $r^2$, hence it suffices to only consider those $7$ numbers.

Comment: What about 4, 5, 6,  in modulo 7? Why don't we consider these?\

Comment: $4$ can be written in the form of $7k-3$. $5$ can be written in the form of $7k-2$, $6$ can be written as $7k-1$.